# Disable AutoDim mode in Cocos2d

Tags: iphone, xcode, cocos2d-iphone

How to stop the screen from automatically dimming after not receiving any user touches in cocos2d?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].idleTimerDisabled = YES;
```

add this in your appDelegate, this will prevent the device to sleep when the app is running.

Comment: Ok im getting 3 errors when I put this in. One is missing [ at start of message send expression, the other two are, expected ], and the last is expected identifier of '('. I can put in the brackets but when I do i still get the identifier error. this is what my .h looks like 'code'                                                        @synthesize window;
@synthesize pauseScreenUp = _pauseScreenUp;


[UIApplication sharedApplication].idleTimerDisabled = YES;'code'

Comment: where did you place the line of code ? put it inside your AppDelegate.m inside applicationDidFinishLaunching

Answer (score 7):

```
[UIApplication sharedApplication].idleTimerDisabled = YES;
```

In order to save battery, you should disable the idle timer only when necessary (i.e. when the user is playing but not when it's browsing the menus).

So it's better to put this code in the `onEnter` function of your Game Layer,
and then add

```
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].idleTimerDisabled = NO;
```

to your  onExit function

Answer (score 0):

The code above should work but try writing it differently like so:

```
id myApplication = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
    [myApplication setIdleTimerDisabled:YES];
```